# react select - how to define component props type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I use `react-select` in my project.
[image]

App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select, { components, OptionProps } from "react-select";

const options = [
  {
    label: "label 1",
    value: "value 1",
    dialCode: "dialCode 1"
  },
  {
    label: "label 2",
    value: "value 2",
    dialCode: "dialCode 2"
  }
];

const { Option } = components;

const IconOption = (props: any) => {
  const { label, dialCode } = props.data;

  return (
    <Option {...props}>
      <div>{label}</div>
      <div>{`(+${dialCode})`}</div>
    </Option>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(options[0]);

  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      value={selected}
      components={{ Option: IconOption }}
    />
  );
}
```

I use `any` type in

```
const IconOption = (props: any) => {
  const { label, dialCode } = props.data;

  return (...);
};
```

When I set the type of the `props` to `OptionProps`, typescript throws error.

```
const IconOption = (props: OptionProps) => {
  const { label, dialCode } = props.data;

  return (...);
};
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-mjo74r?file=/src/App.tsx

**Update 1**

After adding onChange, the typescript throws error again.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select, {
  components,
  OptionProps,
  MultiValue,
  SingleValue
} from "react-select";

type OptionData = {
  label: string;
  value: string;
  dialCode: string;
};

const options: OptionData[] = [
  {
    label: "label 1",
    value: "value 1",
    dialCode: "dialCode 1"
  },
  {
    label: "label 2",
    value: "value 2",
    dialCode: "dialCode 2"
  }
];

const { Option } = components;

const IconOption = (props: OptionProps<OptionData>) => {
  const { label, dialCode } = props.data;

  return (
    <Option {...props}>
      <div>{label}</div>
      <div>{`(+${dialCode})`}</div>
    </Option>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(options[0]);

  const onSelectedChange = (
    newValue: MultiValue<OptionData> | SingleValue<OptionData>
  ) => {
    setSelected(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      value={selected}
      components={{ Option: IconOption }}
      onChange={onSelectedChange}
    />
  );
}
```

error:
[image]

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-mjo74r?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1069

Comment: props: JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & OptionProps<any, boolean, GroupBase<string>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OptionProp` is a generic type. You should declare custom type for option's data and pass it to generic.

```
type OptionData = {
  label: string;
  value: string;
  dialCode: string
}

const options: OptionData[] = [
  {
    label: "label 1",
    value: "value 1",
    dialCode: "dialCode 1"
  },
  {
    label: "label 2",
    value: "value 2",
    dialCode: "dialCode 2"
  }
];

const { Option } = components;

const IconOption = (props: OptionProps<OptionData>) => {
  const { label, dialCode } = props.data;

  return (
    <Option {...props}>
      <div>{label}</div>
      <div>{`(+${dialCode})`}</div>
    </Option>
  );
};
```

Update 1: the ideomatic way to handle union types in TS is adding [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
function isMultiOption<T>(value: MultiValue<T> | SingleValue<T>): value is T[] {
  return Array.isArray(value)
}

function isSingleOption<T>(value: MultiValue<T> | SingleValue<T>): value is T {
  return value != null && !isMultiOption(value)
}

  const onSelectedChange = (
    newValue: MultiValue<OptionData> | SingleValue<OptionData>
  ) => {
    if (newValue == null) {
      return
    }
    if (isMultiOption(newValue)) {
      setSelected(newValue[0]);
    } else if (isSingleOption(newValue)) {
      setSelected(newValue)
    }
  };
```

Comment: can check my update 1 please?